# Follow-up intents aren't getting processed by assistant anymore

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

A few days ago I suddenly noticed that follow-up requests do not reach our (in development) Google Action. Even though the Action still seems to be active after invocation (*see screenshot*), any utterances from that point on just trigger Google Assistant's base functionalities and the current Action context is omitted. Our Action's fullfillment-server did not terminate the session after invocation (it responds with `expectUserResponse: true`). Furthermore there are no follow-up requests shown in the Google console. Our fullfillment-server is not requested at all.

[image]

The other day, several demo users of my application started to encounter that problem as well.

This issue only affects Actions that are currently in development. Live Actions still work.

Is that a Google Assistant bug?

Comment: Is this just happening in the simulator?

Comment: @NickFelker No. It's also happening on devices like my smartphone. In our case (location: Germany), only test apps are affected, but this doesn't seem to be always the case, like stated out in the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved. I didn't change anything but it's working again.